# old computer hang on vga or usb

Tags: graphics-card, bios, freeze, power, capacitor

my old desktop computer start to hang up then restart when display card stressed or even used for video display or irregularly without stressing VGA, I noticed if mouse and keyboard removed "both USB" the computer will last longer to hang up, GPU-z and [Furmark](https://geeks3d.com/furmark/) didn't discover any problem in VGA, I lower the GPU clock from BIOS, but no effect.

I suspect power circuit failure, I checked the capacitors "visually" didn't notice any problem, logged all heat and voltage sensors to files and compared them, no sudden changes when hang up all seems normal even the nominated voltage is slightly higher..

one time after restarting many times repeatedly the BIOS gave warning of checksum error, also I noticed that when hang up and key/mouse display freeze the process like the video sound or calculation using excel will continue until restart which could take up to a minute+ if I didn't force restart.

Comment: "Checksum error" might indicate RAM error. I suggest running [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) as long as possible (overnight?).

Comment: computer will not stay on overnight, it will restart, didn't check on Linux but on win10 will stay 2-3 hour max normally less than 1 hour

Comment: @harrymc yet I suspect irregular DIMM failure or disconnection as one dimm slot already failed, but then no process will continue unless failure in VGA chip.

Comment: Try your luck with a 1-hour run. MemTest86 exercises the RAM, memory controller and even a little the CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalled windows 10-1909, was lazy didn't install Radion 2100 Display driver which is tricky as it's 8 years older than Directx12, the hang decreased significantly.
So the non standard display driver was the reason or maybe some feature of the embedded chip causing the system stop.

Answer (score 0):

uploading `older BIOS` version seems to ease the problem but not solve it totally, MB is very old so irregular hardware failure could be the reason which appear less on the older BIOS.